# Bootstrap vue / Bootstrap side nav toggable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

Hello I am trying to create a side nav with bootstrap-vue. The navbar should auto-collapse together with the header navbar at the breakpoint class="md". The header navbar works as expexted, but the sidenav does not appear when the window passes the breakpoint, nor does it shrink when passing the breakpoint. The code for the sidebar looks like this:

```js
<template>
<b-nav vertical class="wrapper">
    <b-collapse is-nav id="nav_collapse">
      <b-nav-item to="/dashboard">Dashboard</b-nav-item>
      <b-nav-item to="/play">Play</b-nav-item>
      <b-nav-item to="/houses">Houses</b-nav-item>
    </b-collapse>
</b-nav>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Sidebar',
    data: () => {
        return {

        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.wrapper {
    max-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you already worked out the css breakpoints with it?

Comment: are you able to fix this?  I'm looking same type of layput. verticle nav bar with header bar

Comment: Is an update available?